# The 64 bit dll of Microsoft SharePoint is running on 32 bit machine

Tags: dll, sharepoint-2010, windows-services, 32bit-64bit, windows-server-2008-r2

I am working on SharePoint domain. Sometime I need to do development for event receiver and windows service etc.

Last week I have installed a Windows Service on my server to upload the documents from a local folder. Server is 64bit machine and "Windows server 2008 R2" installed on server as OS to run SharePoint Foundation 2010. Service was running properly.

The requirement was, no user will go to the server to upload the document. So I have installed the service on local users machine. Some users were having 32 bit Machine and 32 bit OS and other users are working with 64 bit. while installing the service I got an error on 32 bit machines. Error was "This solution is for 64bit machine". After changing the target platform from 64bit to x86, the service was installed successfully on 32 bit machine and started working properly.

**Now the question came:**

- To work with SharePoint Object Model, I am using SharePoint 64 bit
  dll in my Windows service which is installed on 32 bit machine and 32
  bit OS.
- Is it possible that the 64bit dll will work on 32 bit machine?
- In what scenarios we can face the problem of "64 bit dll will not
  work on 32 bit machine"?
- What should I do if I want to    install the same solution on 64 bit
  and 32 bit machine? I don't want    to change the target platform
  each and every time.

**UPDATE:**

After R&D I found "32 bit solution can be installed on 64 bit dll with some terms and conditions" refer http://www.samlogic.net/articles/32-64-bit-windows-folder-x86-syswow64.htm.

In 64 bit machine we are having Program x86 and SysWOW64 folders to handle the 32 bit dll functionality.

**Now the question is:**

How we are handling the 64 bit dll on 32 bit machines?

And

Is it confirm that the SharePoint dlls are "any CPU"?

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I understand what you are trying to do, so I'll try to be exhaustive:

- SharePoint Object Model are only available on SharePoint servers, not user workstation. They indeed rely on 64 bits DLL that only work on 64bits OS.
- SharePoint 2010 allows you to use the "Client Object Model" that work on remote computer like use workstation. They are .Net DLL, not specific to 32bits or 64bits. Just compile your exe with "Any CPU" and it will work just fine
- Generically speaking, 64bits exe only work on 64bits OS. In .Net you can however use "Any CPU" that will work for both 32bits and 64bits. This however will only work if you exe and its dependencies are full .Net (no native code).

Comment: Thanks @Nico. I did some R&D. Someone added the comment in question body (refer "Update").

Comment: My answer still apply. Client object model is any cpu. SharePoint Server Object Model only work on SharePoint server, not remote computers.

Comment: Yes, but I am little bit confused refer below question.
What should I do if I want to install the same solution on 64 bit and 32 bit machine? I don't want to change the target platform.
I am talking about solutions that are having SharePoint dlls.

Comment: If you talk about "regular" SharePoint DLL, again, there is no ways to use SharePoint DLL outside of a SharePoint Server. And SharePoint server can only be installed on 64bits OS.

Comment: And if you talk about client object model, any CPU solution can be used on both 32bits and 64 bits OS.